# Getting "integer expression expected" error

Tags: bash

I'm receiving the following error when running a script:

> line 6: [: : integer expression expected

I would imagine that the code inside the parenthesis is an integer, however, I can't see where it's going wrong. Please could you tell me how to fix this?

```
if [ "$( df -h | grep hda1 | cut -c40-42)" -ge "80" ]; then 
  echo Subject: Production Server : Low Disk Space : Daily reporting for Server
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if [ "$( df -h | grep hda1 | tr -s ' '|cut -d" " -f 5 | cut -c-2)" -ge 80 ]; then echo Subject: Production Server : Low Disk Space : Daily reporting for Server
```

If you trying to check the % used. I guess, this will be a better way to implement.

Comment: why "if" before "df"?

Comment: aah.. typo.. sorry.. fixing it

Comment: I can't undo my downvote unless you edit your answer again

Comment: @glennjackman: edited. You can undo the downvote now..

Answer (score 1):

`df -h` gives "human readable" output, like 1G or 73M. These obviously aren't integers. Try leaving out the -h. You might have to adjust your cut spacing to match.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of pipes going on...

```
df -h | awk '/hda1/{sub(/%/,"")}$5>80'
```

Will work just as well as cut|grep|cut|tr without the added overhead

Answer (score 0):

This one works fine for me:

```
[[ $(df -h | grep hda1 | cut -c40-42) -ge 80 ]]
```

I edited your question, you were missing the `fi`, was that a typo or is it an error?

Comment: typo; it's on the next line